# Android - Sharing using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, share

I'm wondering if it is possible to change the text that says "SHARE DIALOG EXAMPLE". Where does this text come from?  I'm using the latest SDK (4.10)

[image]

Comment: That is the coming from the app name I would guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is coming from the message you have set up. When you build your ShareLinkContent, add a custom message to say whatever you like. For example,

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.facebook_title))
                .setContentDescription(R.string.custom_msg)
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.social_media_url)))
                .build();
shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```